# ¿Como Consultar el número de elementos asociados a cada etiqueta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Buen día comunidad, estoy practicando MySQL y me tope con un problema que no he podido solucionar, tengo las tablas:

[image: Tablas de la base de datos]

Y quiero consultar cuanto se ha gastado por etiqueta o tag por ejemplo si tengo una etiqueta "Alimentos" y se realizaron compras de productos que tengan dicha etiqueta sumar sus montos y mostrarlos.

De momento este ha sido mi intento:

```
SELECT 
    t.tag_name AS `Etiquetas`,
    SUM((p.price * s.amount)) AS `Consumo`
FROM sales s
JOIN products p
JOIN tags t
JOIN products_tags pt ON pt.product_id = p.prod_id AND pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY `Etiquetas`
ORDER BY `Consumo` DESC;
```

Con la siguiente salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si uno cuenta el consumo de manera manual los valores arrojados no son ni de cerca los correctos, no tengo claro que sea, pero siento que estoy malinterpretando alguna clausura de sql.

**¡Muchas gracias de antemano!**

Comment: Dices que la suma manual no es acertada. Cuál es el resultado de la suma manual?

Comment: De la etiqueta "Alimentos" por ejemplo, manualmente me da 159,92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema está en que `sales` no forma parte de la lógica relacional de la consulta, así que no es raro que retorne resultados inesperados.

Asumiendo que `sales.product` es la columna que se relaciona con `products.prod_id`, entonces la consulta debería ser:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.tag_name AS `Etiquetas`,
    SUM((p.price * s.amount)) AS `Consumo`
FROM sales s
JOIN products p ON p.prod_id=s.product 
JOIN products_tags pt ON pt.product_id=p.prod_id 
JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id=pt.tag_id 
GROUP BY `Etiquetas`
ORDER BY `Consumo` DESC;
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por esta solución! la verdad es que en el tiempo que no pude entrar a la página a revisar logre resolverlo de una forma que es bastante parecida a esta, pero cambie la ubicación del "sales" con "tags", pero se sentía medio frustrante porque quería que "sales" se mantuviera junto al FROM.